# Convert bash function to fish's

Tags: bash, shell, fish

Can someone help me convert this bash function to fish? It would also be nice if you could explain what these do like `"${@%%.app}”`, `'s/ /.*/g’`, `"$@\”` etc.

```
bid() {
    local shortname location

    # combine all args as regex
    # (and remove ".app" from the end if it exists due to autocomplete)
    shortname=$(echo "${@%%.app}"|sed 's/ /.*/g')
    # if the file is a full match in apps folder, roll with it
    if [ -d "/Applications/$shortname.app" ]; then
        location="/Applications/$shortname.app"
    else # otherwise, start searching
        location=$(mdfind -onlyin /Applications -onlyin ~/Applications -onlyin /Developer/Applications 'kMDItemKind==Application'|awk -F '/' -v re="$shortname" 'tolower($NF) ~ re {print $0}'|head -n1)
    fi
    # No results? Die.
    [[ -z $location || $location = "" ]] && echo "$1 not found, I quit" && return
    # Otherwise, find the bundleid using spotlight metadata
    bundleid=$(mdls -name kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier -r "$location")
    # return the result or an error message
    [[ -z $bundleid || $bundleid = "" ]] && echo "Error getting bundle ID for \"$@\"" || echo "$location: $bundleid”
}
```

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: How did you try to resolve this issue on your own?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Some notes on the differences:

- setting variables

  - bash: `var=value`
  - fish: `set var value`
- functions

  - bash

    ```sh
    funcName() {
        ...
    }
    ```
  - fish

    ```sh
    function funcName
        ...
    end
    ```
- function arguments

  - bash: `"$@"`, `"$1"`, `"$2"`, ...
  - fish: `$argv`, `$argv[1]`, `$argv[2]`, ...
- function local variables

  - bash: `local var`
  - fish: `set -l var`
- conditionals I

  - bash: `[[ ... ]]` and `test ...` and `[ ... ]`
  - fish: `test ...` and `[ ... ]`, no `[[ ... ]]`
- conditionals II

  - bash: `if cond; then cmds; fi`
  - fish: `if cond; cmds; end`
- conditionals III

  - bash: `cmd1 && cmd2`
  - fish: `cmd1; and cmd2`
  - fish (as of fish 3.0): `cmd1 && cmd2`
- command substitution

  - bash: `output=$(pipeline)`
  - fish: `set output (pipeline)`
- process substitution

  - bash: `join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`
  - fish: `join (sort file1 | psub) (sort file2 | psub)`

Documentation

- bash: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html
- fish: http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html and https://fishshell.com/docs/current/fish_for_bash_users.html

Comment: I still can’t figure out fish equivalent of `${@%%.app}`. I believe I know what it does i.e. return all the string in `$@` that contain .app at the end. So I would think it would be `$argv[**.app]` in fish but it gives _Could not expand_ error.

Comment: `${@%%.app}` returns a list of all the positional parameters with any ".app" extensions removed. The fish equivalent is `for arg in $argv; set args $args (echo "$arg" | sed 's/.app$//'); end`

Comment: I think you might have made a typo in `sed ’s/.app$//‘` with the $, in the comment above. Otherwise could you please explain why it’s there.

Comment: for each element of the argv array, we're removing the ".app" extension, which appears at the end of the filename. The `$` is the regex "end-of-string" anchor. Actually I should have `sed 's/\.app$//'` escaping the dot.

Comment: Thanks, without escaping the dot, it didn’t give expected results with $.

Comment: You should start a new question and show what you're doing in fish. This does work: `set argv foo.bar.app qux baz.app; for arg in $argv; set args $args (echo "$arg" | sed 's/.app$//'); end; echo $args` outputs `foo.bar qux baz`

Comment: [`bass`](https://github.com/edc/bass) "makes it easy to use utilities written for Bash in fish shell"