# What is the fish equivalent to a bash if/then/else/fi block?

Tags: shell, fish

I am using termux and it has no init system, i found a script to start crond when i start the app

```
if ! pgrep -f "crond" >/dev/null; then
echo "[Starting crond...]" && crond && echo "[OK]"
else
echo "[crond is running]"
fi
```

this code worked perfectly for bash shell.

I am currently using fish shell and tried using the same code in the fish equivalent of bash_profile AKA `config.fish` however, i got the error message

```
Missing end to balance this if statement
if ! pgrep -f "crond" >/dev/null; then
^
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
         called during startup
```

Please help me with translations, I'm reading through fish docs however it will take me a long time to get it right.

Comment: Check `help if`.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service.

Comment: @Cyrus thanks, im doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer by glenn-jackman is very helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/29671880/5257034

i am able to run the code in `config.fish` without issues

my code

```
if ! pgrep -f $crond >/dev/null
echo "[Starting crond...]"; and crond; and echo "[OK]"
else
echo "[crond is running]"
end
```

Comment: The semicolon at the end of the `if` isn't needed. Nor is it needed after the `echo "[crond is running]"`.

Comment: thanks for troubleshooting my code, I removed the semicolons where you mentioned and the code ran fine! hope you don't still think i didn't make an effort

Answer (score 1):

You should start with the [tutorial](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html). There you will learn that `if` blocks look like this:

```
if pgrep -f "crond" >/dev/null
    do_something
end
```