# How to convert a bash function to a fish function?

Tags: bash, function, shell, syntax, fish

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667714/convert-bash-function-to-fishs) and the documentation, I was trying to create a fish function for a PR on [gokechan/lf](https://github.com/gokcehan/lf) package to get [lfcd](https://github.com/gokcehan/lf/wiki/Tutorial#working-directory) working in fish.

This is the bash function that I am trying to convert:

```
lfcd () {
tmp="$(mktemp)"
lf -last-dir-path="$tmp" "$@"
if [ -f "$tmp" ]; then
    dir="$(cat "$tmp")"
    rm -f "$tmp"
    if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
        if [ "$dir" != "$(pwd)" ]; then
            cd "$dir"
        fi
    fi
fi
}
```

And this is the fish function I've adapted from the function above:

```
function lfcd
set tmp "(mktemp)"
lf -last-dir-path="$tmp" "$argv"
if [ -f "$tmp" ];
    set dir "(cat "$tmp")"
    rm -f "$tmp"
    if [ -d "$dir" ];
        if [ "$dir" != "(pwd)" ];
            cd "$dir"
        end
    end
end
end
```

So far the function runs lf but it does not open the last selected directory on exit.

I have 0 experience creating fish functions or translating bash to fish.
This is my introductory fish project, so any help or guidance will be much appreciated!

Comment: Don't put fish command substitution in quotes: `set tmp (mktemp)` -- you're setting the tmp variable to the literal string `(mktemp)`

Comment: @glennjackman would the same apply to the line with ```set dir "(cat "$tmp")"``` ?

Comment: Yes, all of them.

Comment: thanks @glennjackman looks like that did the trick, I can make my PR now!

Answer (score 1):

**Most of the time**, it's not strictly necessary to quote variables in fish: word splitting is not a feature of fish.

You could write:

```
function lfcd
    set tmp (mktemp)
    lf -last-dir-path=$tmp $argv
    if [ -f $tmp ]
        set dir (cat $tmp)
        rm -f $tmp
        [ -d $dir ]; and [ $dir != (pwd) ]; and cd $dir
    end
end
```