# Converting bash to fish function (use rga-fzf in fish)

Tags: bash, zsh, fish, fzf

I am trying to convert this bash/zsh function into fish. I want to use rga-fzf which is a function for zsh/bash using fzf together with [ripgrep-all](https://github.com/phiresky/ripgrep-all).

(my default shell is fish)

Here's the zsh/fish function:

```
rga-fzf() {
    RG_PREFIX="rga --files-with-matches"
    local file
    file="$(
        FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND="$RG_PREFIX '$1'" \
            fzf --sort --preview="[[ ! -z {} ]] && rga --pretty --context 5 {q} {}" \
                --phony -q "$1" \
                --bind "change:reload:$RG_PREFIX {q}" \
                --preview-window="70%:wrap"
    )" &&
    echo "opening $file" &&
    xdg-open "$file"
}
```

This is how far I got on my own, and with some help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667714/convert-bash-function-to-fishs) which helps - and [this post](https://www.cafe-encounter.net/p3107/fish-shell-quickstart-for-converting-bash-scripts).

```
function fif
    set RG_PREFIX rga --files-with-matches
    set -l file
    set file (
        set FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND $RG_PREFIX "$1" \
            fzf --sort --preview test ! -z {} && rga --pretty --context 5 $argv {} \
                --phony -q "$1" \
                --bind "change:reload:$RG_PREFIX $argv" \
                --preview-window="70%:wrap"
    ) &&
    open "$file"
end
```

However, now it simply opens the (current) folder and the notification

```
error: Found argument '--phony' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
```

If I change the $1 to $argv then there's no change. Also no change if I change $argv to "$argv"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
If I change back the line to :

```
            fzf --sort --preview "[[ ! -z {} ]] && rga --pretty --context 5 {q} {}" \
```

Then the error is gone but it only still opens the folder and not fzf

**EDIT 2**

I've changed back the `{q}`

so now it reads:

```
function fif
    set RG_PREFIX rga --files-with-matches
    set -l file
    set file (
        set FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND $RG_PREFIX "$argv" \
            fzf --sort --preview "[[ ! -z {} ]] && rga --pretty --context 5 {q} {}" \
                --phony -q "$1" \
                --bind "change:reload:$RG_PREFIX {q}" \
                --preview-window="70%:wrap"
    ) &&
    open "$file"
end
```

The error is gone.
But the problem persists, it's not actually opening up fzf.

**EDIT 3**
I did something wrong with the first set. This shouldn't be

```
set RG_PREFIX rga --files-with-matches
```

but

```
set -x RG_PREFIX rga --files-with-matches
```

moreover, everything between the () after the fzf should stay the same
so currently I'm here:

```
function fif
    set -x RG_PREFIX rga --files-with-matches
    set -l file
    set file (
        FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND="$RG_PREFIX '$1'" \
            fzf --sort --preview="[[ ! -z {} ]] && rga --pretty --context 5 {q} {}" \
                --phony -q "$1" \
                --bind "change:reload:$RG_PREFIX {q}" \
                --preview-window="70%:wrap"
    ) &&
    open "$file"
end
```

Now it at least opens up fzf but it doesn't actually use rga to filter any of the documents (fzf opens up all the available files in the folder) and the preview window shows:

```
fish: Unknown command: '[[ ! -z FILENAME ]]' 
fish: 
[[ ! -z 'FILENAME' ]] && rga  --pretty --context 5 '' 'FILENAME'
```

whereby FILENAME is something like Guidelines 2-2019.pdf

so Mmm one step closer, but not actually using `rga` and `fzf` together.

Comment: Why did you remove the `--preview="<this   and this>"`?

Comment: Because I thought you were supposed to change [[ ]] to test 

If I change it back, the error is gone, but it still only opens the folder.

Comment: So what? Keep it `--preview="test blablablablabla"` anyway. You removed `"` and removed `=`. Also why change `{q}` to `$argv`? You are running that in fish - the part in `preview` will be run inside `fzf` using your default shell, which may not be fish.

Comment: Thanks, 
I've changed back the ```{q}``` 
(see edit 2 above) It still doesn't open up fzf however. the error is gone though (yay!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function fif
    set -x RG_PREFIX rga --files-with-matches
    set -l file
    set file (
        FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND="$RG_PREFIX '$argv'" \
            fzf --sort --preview="[ ! -z {} ] && rga --pretty --context 5 {q} {}" \
                --phony -q "$argv" \
                --bind "change:reload:$RG_PREFIX {q}" \
                --preview-window="70%:wrap"
    ) &&
    open "$file"
end
```

This is what worked in the end!